# JQUERY: How do I know if this element is currently open/closed (slidetoggle)

Tags: php, jquery

Im using the following to open/close a div

```
$(".alerts").click(function(){

    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(50);
```

But I want a certain function to trigger only if the box was closed and is being opened, how can I determine this?  I prefer not to use cookies or anything like that

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `visible` selector with the `is` method like this -

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".alerts").click(function()
    {        
        if($(this).toggleClass("active").next().is(":visible"))
            alert("It's visible");

        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(50);
    });
});
```

An example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fpCcq/).

The -

```
if($(this).toggleClass("active").next().is(":visible"))
    alert("It's visible");
```

portion is checking to see if the next element of `this` is visible or not. If it is, then it returns true. As a result, the `alert` method gets executed.

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) is the documentation for the `visible` selector and [here](http://api.jquery.com/is/) is the documentation for the `is()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the div and check for it with [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

```
$('.alerts').live('click', function() {
   if($(this).hasClass('active')) //close
      $(this).removeClass('active').next().slideUp(50); 
   else //open
      $(this).addClass('active').next().slideDown(50); 
});
```

When checking for DOM elements/attributes that have been changed by Javascript, use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) rather than e.g. `click()`.

If your `.alerts` element has a different CSS style when it has the `.active` class, you should run the `addClass()` and `removeClass()` functions *after* the slide events have completed, like so:

```
//same thing, but wait for animation to complete
$('.alerts').live('click', function() {
   var thisbtn = $(this);
   if(thisbtn.hasClass('active')) { //close
      thisbtn.next().slideUp(50, function() {
         thisbtn.removeClass('active');
      });
   } else { //open
      thisbtn.next().slideDown(50, function() {
         thisbtn.addClass('active');
      });
   }
});
```